# Spring MVC: generate ModelAndView programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am wondering is it possible to generate ModelAndView's output programatically and not via controller's return parameter. For example:
I have the following method that returns a compiled html:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-list", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = BaseController.AJAX_HEADER)
public ModelAndView getList(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = true) Integer page,
            @ActiveUser User activeUser) {
        ModelAndView result = null;

        try {
            result = new ModelAndView("administration/events-log/list");
            result.addObject("events", eventsLogService.getList(page, Config.RECORDS_PER_PAGE));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log(e, activeUser.getUsername());
        }

        return result;
    }
```

What I want is to create something like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get-list", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = BaseController.AJAX_HEADER)
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String, Object> getList(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = true) Integer page,
            @ActiveUser User activeUser) {
        HashMap<String, Object> json = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        try {
            json.put("error", 0);
            ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView("administration/events-log/list");
            result.addObject("events", eventsLogService.getList(page, Config.RECORDS_PER_PAGE));

            json.put("content", result);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            /**/
        }

        return json;
    }
```

so the JSON object that will be sended back to the client will look:
{'error': 0, 'content': compiled_html}

Any thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ModelAndView` has no output. It just knows the name of the view. The rendering of the view is independent of Spring MVC.

If you simply want to send `JSON` that contains some `HTML` you can put the `JSON` code directly on your jsp. Change your java code like that:

```
result = new ModelAndView("path/to/json");
result.addObject("events", eventsLogService.getList(page, Config.RECORDS_PER_PAGE));
result.addObject("html", "administration/events-log/list");
```

Your `JSON` jsp can look like this:

```
<%@ page contentType="application/json" %>
{
  "error": "0",
  "content": "<jsp:include page="${html}" />"
}
```

Please note that this code is just for illustration. You may have adapt it to your situation. And you have to escape the included `HTML` to get valid `JSON`.

Comment: And how can I call a JSP renderer?

Comment: @nKognito It's much more complicated than it sounds. For every `jsp` a java class is generated. This class is responsible for writing the content to the response. The details are somewhat server dependent. The name of the class could be `org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.myjsp_jsp` e.g. and you would have to know which methods to call in which order.

Comment: but it's only jsp, I mean without any model parameters... Ok, as I understand it's impossible to do that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If your jsp contains plain html, then you could read the source. But usually they contain at least `<%@ page ..%>`and use tags from taglibs.

Comment: Yes, but what about arguments that I pass as a model.. Will the page contain that information too?

Comment: @nKognito If you read the source of a jsp, then It won't. But as I wrote in my answer: You can have a jsp that contains the `JSON` and includes the view you want to add with `<jsp:include>`. This will give you exactly the result that you want.

Comment: Aaa, ok I understand. But unfortunatelly I need it vice versa i.e. JSON object that contains an html output